# my jquery for slider event is working wrongly in my angular 2 table

Tags: jquery, angular

Whenever I clicked or dragged the slider the contents of the table are flickering, and sometimes the values are also changing automatically;
what am I missing?

```
    ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.sliderElt = $(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('.slider');
    this.sliderElt.slider({
        range: true,
        orientation: "horizontal",
        min: 1,
        max: 100,
        step: 1,
        values: this.value,
        slide: (event, ui) => {
            this.onChange(ui.values);
        },
        change: (event, ui) => {
            console.log('change');
        }

    });
```

And the Angular 2 part,

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="#x of data">
    <td>
      <span>{{x.NUMBER}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>{{x.DETAIL}}</td>
    <td>{{x.DATE}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I don't see anything Angular2 related in your question. How is this related to Angular2?

Comment: iam using this jquery in my angular 2 application.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there and please format your code properly.

Comment: You should absolutely not be mixing jQuery and Angular in this way -- they're going to collide.  Let Angular control the DOM, don't rummage around yourself setting classes based on document-level events.

Comment: then what i have to do, in order to achieve this?

Comment: Rewrite your code in Angular, basically. Use ng-class to set DOM classes based on the scope data, and set ng-click events via a directive instead of binding events to DOM nodes.   Transitioning from jquery dev work to angular means unlearning a lot of habits; much of what you're used to is the exact opposite of how it should be done in Angular.

Comment: what iam missing on this??

Comment: i have edited my question

Comment: then how i have to use jquery in angular 2